# internet explorer 8 truncates iframe contents

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe

**[the demo is here](http://brazilwide.com.br/debug/iframe_issue.html)**
(can't reproduce it on jsfiddle, since they don't allow ajax to sufficient extent)

Imagine, you have iframe on your page

```
<iframe id="if1" src="/some/url">  </iframe>
```

`/some/url` returns simple text: `<form>text</form><br/>`

And also, once iframe is loaded, you access its contents from Javascript.

```
var io = document.getElementById('if1');
alert(io.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
```

Normal browsers, obviously, return content exactly as it is. But internet explorer 8 returns something funny

```
text</FORM><BR>
```

Even though right-click/view-source on iframe shows correct content: `<form>text</form><br/>`

I didn't try other IE versions.

Did you see this issue before? This is a very simplified version of the problem I've met while adapting webapp to IE. Basically, I do ajax requests through iframe (not xhr, I need to upload files) and html fragments are returned.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmmm. Have you tried giving the inner frame a full, valid structure (`<html><head>....`)?

Comment: Also, I notice you are not sending a `content-type` along with the inlying document. That shouldn't make a difference because the .html will automatically be interpreted as HTML, but it would still be a good thing to send it along

Comment: agreed with @Pekka's first point -- iframe expects its contents to be a complete HTML document.

Comment: @Pekka I'm sending html fragments in response to ajax request. But that's an interesting idea, I should be able to create 'fake wrapping'.

Comment: @Pekka @Spudley But how did people solve it before XHR, when they used iframes for ajax more often?

Comment: @Nikita you mean using iframes to get HTML snippets as opposed to whole pages? I think that kind of thing mainly came up with Ajax...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `body` around response worked, funny I didn't think of it right away.

And the best thing, there's no need to change front-end: `document.body.innerHTML` will return content without `body` tag (naturally).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jQuery to see if that is any better?

```
alert($('#if1').html());
```